# Integrating YouTube videos with FlowPlayer

Tags: php, html, video, youtube, flowplayer

Im using flow player commercial licence, worndering how to integrate and let the player play an YouTube hosted video, Im sure there must be a way, I found some examples too, but not working.

```
   <div id="player" class="flowplayer yt-iphone" data-engine="youtube" data-embed="false">
      <video>
         <source type="video/youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkI0UB4zXMI&feature=youtu.be">
      </video>
   </div>
```

ANy body had this requirement? can you help me if you know any info on playing videos with youtube links.

Comment: You are using the HTML5 ```<video>``` tag and put a Youtube URL as the file name (which is a HTML document and not a video file), have a look at Flowplayer's official documents, there are a few examples for embedding Youtube videos with it.

Comment: @chrki Hi, thank you, but I could not see any related articles there, so why posted here, I feel it must be a simple trick, can you post me if you find any examples or documents on that?

Comment: Sorry I think I was wrong, it was demo code for a plugin that costs an additional $100...